# Linq grouping by same data

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make a LINQ query that will find artists with more than 1 album released in the same year. My query is:

```
 from ar in artists
 join al in albums on ar.ArtistID equals al.ArtistID into allAlbumsByArtist
 let albumsByYear = allAlbumsByArtist.GroupBy(a => a.YearPublished)
 where albumsByYear.Count() > 1
 select ar;
```

But for some reason, this query gives me artists by total album count. I've tried dissecting it step by step:

```
var artistsAndAlbums =
    from ar in artists
    join al in albums on ar.ArtistID equals al.ArtistID into allAlbumsByArtist
    select new { Artist = ar, AllAlbums = allAlbumsByArtist };
```

and then

```
foreach (var item in artistsAndAlbums)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Artist.Name);
    var albumsByYear = item.AllAlbums.GroupBy(a => a.YearPublished);
    foreach (var al in albumsByYear)
        Console.WriteLine(al.Count() > 1);
}
```

and it works well, however, the first SQL-like query gives me the artist with most albums, not the one with more than 1 album released in the same year. Been trying to figure out what's wrong, but can't find the matter.

Comment: "Doesn't work" and "doesn't get me the right result" doesn't give us any information about what's actually wrong. Please provide input data, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing input data, expected output data and actual output data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for some reason, this query gives me artists by total album count.

This is because of the condition

```
where albumsByYear.Count() > 1
```

`albumsByYear` is a **collection** of groupings, so your criteria is basically saying to include artists that have albums for more than one year.

What you really need is like this:

```
where albumsByYear.Any(grouping => grouping.Count() > 1)
```